# Simultaneous Orthogonal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

Given a smooth bounded set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, there is a simultaneous orthogonal basis for  $L^2(U)$ and $H^1_0(U)$ by the existence of eigenvectors to the Laplacian in a bounded domain, which particularly requires boundedness for compactness of the solution operator of the corresponding elliptic problem. Is it possible to construct a simultaneous orthogonal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as well?

I thought it might be possible to use a basis for $L^2(U)$ where U is a cube and then by translations and dilations construct an orthogonal basis for  $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I do not know if that will also be orthogonal basis for  $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or if there will be some edge effects creating trouble.

I wanted to know because I was reading the existence of solutions to wave equations as given in Evans's book on Partial Differential Equations using the Galerkin Method and at one point it requires this simultaneous basis for $L^2(U)$ and $H^1_0(U)$, which is available only for bounded smooth domains $U$ and I wonder if that proof could be extended for existence in $[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^n$.

Any help would be most welcome.

**Possible Solution**:

Looking at the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686654/patching-up-basis-for-l2-mathbbrn), I split $\mathbb{R}^n$ into the integer lattice $U_k:=U+k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, and where $U$ is the unit cube. For $L^2(U_k)$, there is an orthonormal basis $\{e_l^k; k\in\mathbb{Z}^n, l\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ which are also eigenvectors of the Laplacian $-\Delta$, and therefore, it also forms an orthogonal basis for $H_0^1(U_k)$. Now, we may extend each $e_n^k$ outside $U_k$ by $0$ so that it belongs to $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. These $\{e_l^k; k\in\mathbb{Z}^n, l\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ form an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and also an orthogonal basis for $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Could someone confirm if this reasoning is correct or am I missing out some issue?

Comment: I think your construction at least doesn't work when $n=1$.  In $\mathbb{R}^1$, $H^1$ functions are continuous and $H^1$ convergence implies local uniform convergence, in particular pointwise convergence.  All of your functions $e^k_l$ vanish on $\mathbb{Z}$, so they can't approximate in $H^1$ norm any function that doesn't.  Hence their span is not dense.  For $n > 1$ I'm not sure but I think your claim that your functions are an orthonormal basis for $H^1$ needs a careful proof.

Comment: Thank you, I just saw that laplacian has continuous spectrum for $n=1$ and realised I was making a mistake somewhere. But for $n>1$, I do not require the $H^1$ basis to be orthonormal, only orthogonal. I'll check again.

Comment: I misread, I should have said "orthogonal" not "orthonormal".  I don't dispute your functions are orthogonal in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^1)$, but they're not a basis.

Comment: I'm sorry I might be asking something trivial but I thought it only meant that the class of functions had a continuous representative, so that sets of measure zero would not play a role.

Comment: Ok, I realized I was making a mistake in proving that it is a basis for $H^1$, the restriction to $U_k$, only being a basis for $H_0^1(U_k)$ means that I cannot use it. What I need is a simultaneous basis for $L^2(U_k)$ and $H^1(U_k)$ for this approach to work.

Comment: Well, there's no harm in identifying each class in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^1)$ with its unique continuous representative.  Or to rephrase what I said, for any class in the closed span of your $e_i^k$, its continuous representative vanishes on the integers.  Thus (the class of) any continuous function that doesn't vanish on the integers will not be in the closed span.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that a simultaneous basis for $L^2(U_k)$ and $H^1(U_k)$ will solve the problem.  Those functions generally won't vanish on $\partial U_k$ so you can't extend them by 0 as before.  You may be able to extend them some other way, but then functions coming from disjoint $U_k$ won't have disjoint support and it's not clear how to get them to be orthogonal.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here within a few days, this might be a good question for MathOverflow.  I'm curious now too, so I'll probably post it there eventually if you don't :)

Comment: Cross-posted on MathOverflow http://mathoverflow.net/questions/159463/simultaneous-orthogonal-basis-for-l2-mathbbrn-and-h1-mathbbrn