# Patching up basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Given an orthogonal basis for $L^2(I)$ where $I\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is the unit cube, can we construct an orthogonal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by translations/dilations etc.?

Any reference to such a construction?

Comment: What other operations do you allow exactly? Addition? Fourier transform? If you allow addition, you don't even need an ONB to start with---e.g. the Haar basis from just $\chi_{[0,1)}$. If you allow the inverse Fourier transform, take the usual ONB on the circle, shift it to cover all frequency bands. This decomposes $L^2$ into a Hilbert direct sum. Take the inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: Actually the ONB I had for $L^2(I)$ has some extra properties which I wanted to see if they could be extended to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but this basis by decomposing $L^2$ as a Hilbert direct sum looks interesting, could you elaborate on it a little or cite a reference? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any countable partition of a measure space $X$ into disjoint subsets $E_n$ of positive measure we have $L^2(X)$ isomorphic to the direct (orthogonal) sum of the spaces $L^2(E_n)$. Consequently, an orthonormal  basis for $L^2(X)$ can be obtained by taking the union of orthonormal bases for each $L^2(E_n)$. In your case, the set of integer translates  of basis functions for $L^2(I)$ forms an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$.

Dilations are a different story. Of course, if all functions are dilated by the same factor, nothing really changes: you still get a basis from lattice translations.   But if different dilation factors are used, your basis for $L^2(I)$ has to be very special in order for orthogonality to hold.

Check out [Mathematical theory of wavelets](http://www.nato-us.org/analysis2000/papers/weiss.pdf) by Weiss and Wilson.